# I want to extract data with formatting from jexcel library

Tags: android, android-studio, jexcelapi

I am creating an app which will view excel files within my app without going to any third party app. So for this i have used jexcel library.

I am able to retrieve data from any Excel file through this library.
This is my code.

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void order(View v) {
    try {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open("Information.xls");
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
        Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
        int row = s.getRows();
        int col = s.getColumns();

        String xx = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                Cell z = s.getCell(c, i);
                xx = xx + z.getContents();

                xx = xx + "\t\t";
            }

            xx = xx + "\n";
        }

        display(xx);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void display(String value)
{
    TextView x=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    x.setText(value);
}
}
```

I am using android studio as my platform –

This is the screenshot of my output.

[OutputScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oAZJ.png).

I'm only able to view content of Excel file without formatting(e.g. Bold,Italic) and images in my app. I want to display all content of Excel sheet with proper formatting and images.  Is there any function through which i can get to know the formatting of the file and set it on my viewer.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what is not working.

Comment: It's not cool to have your source code in a link. Please show here what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: I am new to this forum so sorry for the inconvenience. I have edited my question.

Comment: As a rule ... the better quality your question ... the better answers you get. Remember the value of this site is the large number of high quality questions ... with quality answers ... think of those who come after you.

Comment: I've done a fair amount of work with excel using other libraries. I can't see where you're asking for style information. I suggest looking through jexcelapi for something similar.

Comment: jexcelapi get cell style https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jexcelapi+get+cell+style

Comment: CellFormat b = (CellFormat) z.getCellFormat() 
Through this i am getting the formatting parameters like align and font records. I want to set these parameters to my textview.

Comment: It looks like you have most of the answer now. The remaining issues are just formatting the output.

Comment: Yes. That is the only issue i am facing right now. Can you please help me with the formatting.